# Powershell. How do I export the resulting array in Excel?

Tags: powershell, selenium, phantomjs

I carry out the parsing using Powershell and Selenium.

With the command `$fullstory = $ie.FindElementByClassName("comment")`

I get the output:

```
Artist: Pink Floyd
Album Title: Dark Side Of the Moon
Genre: Rock
Year: 2016
```

I want to export it to Excel, with "Artist", "Album Title", etc, as column headings and the data after the colon as the values of the column?

Comment: It's unclear how you want the data in Excel, do you want Artist, Album Title, Genre & Year as column titles and the data underneath them in the column? Or In the same layout as you currently have but with `:` as the cell delimiter?

Comment: Hello James C. Sorry! I want to get this like "Artist, Album Title, Genre & Year as column titles and the data underneath them in the column"

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), your single line of code isn't enough to be able to help as I don't know what data type your output is.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object, then use `Export-CSV` to export it to a `.csv` file.

Here is an example assuming that `$fullstory` is a `[string]` and not an array of strings. If it is an array of strings, remove `$nl` line and the `.split($nl)`.

```
$fullstory = $ie.FindElementByClassName("comment")
$nl = [Environment]::NewLine
$output = [pscustomobject]@{}
foreach ($line in $fullstory.split($nl)) {
    $split = $line.split(":")
    $PropertyName = $split[0].Trim()
    $PropertyValue = $split[1].Trim()
    Add-Member -InputObject $output -Name $PropertyName -Value $PropertyValue -MemberType NoteProperty
}
$output | Export-CSV C:\example\example.csv -notypeinformation
```